# makefile in virtualenv is compiling to wrong python version

Tags: python, makefile, virtualenv, qmake

My machine is running python 2.6, with a virtual environment running 2.7.

I enter the virtualenv and run `configure`, `make`, then `make install` to build an application (*pyqt4 FWIW*).

My problem: when I compile the application, its done with python 2.6.

How can I tell it to use the version of the virtual environment (2.7).

I have confirmed the virtual environment does indeed have 2.7 and I have set the python alias to `python2.7`, but no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virtualenv` only provides the environment for `python`, `easy_install` and `pip`, but not `make`. you could run the following to verify:

```
which make
```

According to [instruction](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html) here, I guess you need to run the following command:

```
python configure-ng.py
```

which should trigger the correct python in virtualenv.

Comment: the instructions don't state *-ng will work with virtualenv. What makes you think it will?

Comment: because './configure' and 'make' would not trigger python, but 'configure-ng.py' will. It's the python that makes difference for virtualenv.